# Screens Rendering Issue on iPhone 4-inch Screen

Tags: ios, iphone

All the screens for my App do not stretch to cover all the real estate of 4-inch device screen. It renders fine for 3.5 inch. Toggle the 'Use Auto Layout' makes no difference;  everything on story board looks good when toggle the left-most control in story-board to switch between '3.5-inch' form factor and '4-inch form factor'. 
See following screen-shots from 4-inch simulator. It does not work on 4-inch device either.

Anyone knows the possible cause of the problem?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are not setting the splash screen for 4-inch retina display. Please check for Default-568h@2x.png image in your bundle. If you have splash screen with other name please rename it to Default-568h@2x.png

If this image is missing please add this image in bundle and set it as launch image.

Comment: The launch screen is set properly; however I think what you pointed out could be one of the cause of the problem. I found out my issue, will update the post. Thanks, Mayank!

Answer (score 1):

I found out the cause of the problem.  Under the 'App Icons' section of the project, I chose 'Don't use asset catalogs', and do not know why, the screens rendered wrongly. After I use asset catalog, everything is fine now.